# SQL Server 2018 How can I group information in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table that is in this (horribly messy) format. This is a snapshot of the middle columns of the table which is why there are large holes in the data (other columns have stuff in them for these rows).

```
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|    upsell1    |      upsell2       |   upsell3    |   upsell4    |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|               |                    | Car Kit      | Scented Tabs |
|               |                    |              |              |
|               |                    |              |              |
|               | Fiters             |              |              |
| NULL          | NULL               | NULL         | NULL         |
|               |                    |              |              |
|               | Car Kit            | Scented Tabs |              |
|               |                    |              |              |
|               |                    |              |              |

+---------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm looking to get an output that groups and counts each product no matter which column it appears in.

```
+--------------+---------------+
|   Product    | Product Count |
+--------------+---------------+
| Car Kit      |             2 |
| Scented Tabs |             2 |
| Fiters       |             1 |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Normally if it were all in one column it would be easy enough to use a group by command to have X as column 1 and count(X) as column 2 but I'm blanking on a way to get this disparate information to group together properly.

Note: I can't change the structure of the table (much to my chagrin)

Comment: As you have discovered you are fighting this because of the non-normalized design. You are going to have to convert those columns to rows (UNPIVOT or UNION) and then do a standard count.

Comment: Are the spaces in you sample `NULL` or empty string?

Comment: empty spaces are empty strings (but there are also NULLS for some insane reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `apply`:

```
select v.upsell, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (upsell1), (upsell2), (upsell3), (upsell4)) v(upsell)
where v.upsell is not null
group by v.upsell;
```

Your question is a little unclear on what the blanks are.  You might want:

```
where v.upsell is not null and v.upsell <> ''
```

or even:

```
where v.upsell is not null and ltrim(rtrim(v.upsell)) <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no control over the terrible schema...

```
with CTE as
(
select upsell1 as product, 1 as counter
from MyTable
where upsell1 is not null

union all
select upsell2, 1
from MyTable
where upsell2 is not null

union all
select upsell3, 1
from MyTable
where upsell3 is not null

union all
select upsell4, 1
from MyTable
where upsell4 is not null
)
select product, sum(counter)
from CTE
group by product
```

Comment: Will this count both if there is the same data in more than 1 upsell field?

Comment: @tomdemaine yes. Union all does not remove duplicates fromt he results. That said, Gordon has the better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try it's.

```
    declare @test table (
    upsell1 varchar(100),
    upsell2 varchar(100),       
    upsell3 varchar(100),
    upsell4 varchar(100)

)
insert into @test values ('','','Car Kit','Scented Tabs')
insert into @test values ('','','','')
insert into @test values ('','','','')
insert into @test values ('','Fiters','','')
insert into @test values (null,null,null,null)
insert into @test values ('','','','')
insert into @test values ('','Car Kit','Scented Tabs','')
insert into @test values ('','','','')
insert into @test values ('','','','')

select 
    abc,
    count(*) 
from (
select *
from @test) as src
unpivot (
abc for anyThing in (upsell1,upsell2,upsell3,upsell4)
) as ttt
group by abc
```

Comment: Please give it an alias `Product Count`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no type assumptions, I would pick safe method with UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (VALUES
    ('','','Car Kit','Scented Tabs'),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','Fiters','',''),
    (null,null,null,null),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','Car Kit','Scented Tabs',''),
    ('','','',''),
    ('','','','')
) T(upsell1,upsell2,upsell3,upsell4)

SELECT Product, COUNT(Product) [Product Count] FROM
(
    SELECT
        CAST(upsell1 AS nvarchar(MAX)) upsell1,
        CAST(upsell2 AS nvarchar(MAX)) upsell2,
        CAST(upsell3 AS nvarchar(MAX)) upsell3,
        CAST(upsell4 AS nvarchar(MAX)) upsell4
    FROM #t
) T
UNPIVOT (Product for X IN (upsell1,upsell2,upsell3,upsell4)) P
WHERE Product != ''
GROUP BY Product
```

**Result**

```
Product         Product Count
--------------- -------------
Car Kit         2
Fiters          1
Scented Tabs    2
```